# Music notation software for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I am looking for a music notation software with which I can write and edit music scores. A good proprietary example would be [Guitar Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_Pro).

[image]

What are some good free software alternative?

Comment: This question is quite broad. Could you specify the features you need precisely?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The top music notation software are:

1. [**MidiEditor**](https://www.midieditor.org/index.php?category=download) Graphical interface to edit, play, and record Midi data. Last Update: 2018-06-05
2. [**MuseScore**](https://musescore.org/) is a Graphical WYSIWYG music score typesetter. It has following features:

   - Unlimited number of staves
   - Up to four voices per staff
   - Notes can be entered with mouse, keyboard or via midi
   - Can import/export MusicXml and SMF files

   To install MuseScore, run the following commands from the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install musescore
   ```
3. [**NoteEdit**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/noteedit.berlios/) is a KDE editor. It supports an unlimited number and length of staffs, polyphony, a MIDI playback of written notes, chord markings, lyrics, a number of import and export filters to many formats like MIDI, MusicXML, ABC Music, MUP, PMX, MusiXTeX, LilyPond, ...
4. [**Canorus**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/canorus/) is a free cross-platform music score editor. It supports an unlimited number and length of staffs, polyphony, a MIDI playback of notes, chord markings, lyrics, import/export filters to formats like MIDI, MusicXML, ABC Music, MusiXTeX and LilyPond.

   For Ubuntu 13.10 and prior versions, you can install Canorus by running the commands given below from terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install canorus
   ```

   For Ubuntu 14.04 and later versions, download Canorus from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/canorus/) and install it.
5. [**Denemo**](http://www.denemo.org/) is a GTK frontend to Lilypond. Download Denemo from [here](http://www.denemo.org/downloads-page/) and install it!
6. [**Lilypond**](http://lilypond.org/) aims to print music as if it were engraved by hand. It is used to produce musical scores that are engraved with traditional layout rules.

   To install [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org/unix.html), run the commands given below from terminal:

   > Note: LilyPond is a text-based music engraver; it is more similar to a programming language than a graphical score editing program.

   So better install [one of the frontends](https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=22) like: Frescobaldi:

   ```
   sudo apt install frescobaldi
   ```
7. [**Rosegarden**](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/) is a music composition and editing environment based around a MIDI sequencer that features a rich understanding of music notation and includes basic support for digital audio.

   To install Rosegarden, run the commands given below from terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install rosegarden
   ```
8. [**TuxGuitar**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/) is a multitrack guitar tablature editor and player written in Java-SWT. It can open GuitarPro, PowerTab and TablEdit files.

   To install TuxGuitar, run the commands given below from terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install tuxguitar
   ```

#### Helpful links

- [UbuntuStudio/Notation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/Notation)
- [8 Best Free Linux Music Notation Software](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20111009053119125/MusicNotation.html)

Comment: If you're looking for a guitar specific notation software, I actually recommend [tuxguitar](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/tuxguitar) which I've been using for a long time to open Guitar Pro files.  I also do use and recommend musescore which has been already suggested by others.  Both should be available through your distros repos.

Comment: MuseScore blew me away, it is the first score editor I tried that felt amazing: "Easy to use,
yet powerful" as truthfully advertised on their website. Perhaps specially now that there's a company behind it paying full time devs since 2018 according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 19):

**Engraving:**

http://lilypond.org/ - `sudo apt-get install lilypond`

- Designed primarily for music notation
- Optical font scaling
- Special ledger line handling
- Proportional spacing
- Inspired by Rosegarden (below)

http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/ - `sudo apt-get install rosegarden`

- Music Notation
- Editing
- MIDI support
- Audio Mixing
- JACK Support
- Based on the Rosegarden project was started in 1993 at the University of Bath

https://musescore.org/ - `sudo apt-get install musescore`

- Large range of supported filetypes (incl. Guitar Pro)
- Online Score Sharing
- Export to images and/or audio
- WYSIWYG Support

http://www.denemo.org/ - Download [Here](http://www.denemo.org/downloads-page/)

- WYSIWYG Support
- Primarily for notation
- Accepts MIDI input
- JACK client

**Guitar Tab:**

http://www.tuxguitar.com.ar/ - `sudo apt-get install tuxguitar`

- Tab editor
- Supports Guitar Pro import & export
- Midi Editor
- Written in Java

**Editing:**

http://frescobaldi.org/ `sudo apt-get install frescobaldi`

- An editor for Lilypond music files (above)
- Text editor with syntax highlighting
- MIDI Player
- Score wizard
- Snippet manager

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good list, but since these are extremely different projects it might be good to add a sentence highlighting the most characteristic specialties of each of them.

Answer (score 5):

What about trying [Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/) - it is in the repositories, so a simple `sudo apt-get install rosegarden`does the trick.

I am not certain it's the best alternative, but `Rosegarden` exists for more than 8yrs and is in active development.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be an ideal solution for everyone, but Ubuntu Studio has a vast lineup of music production applications for linux within its audio/core/plugins package. Including music score applications like some of the above mentioned, as well as native synth/effects/midi virtual instruments, VST/VSTi plugin wrappers and various DAW's.

although, with that said its recommended to run a low-latency kernel with some of these applications.

Ubuntu Studio Audio:

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-core ubuntustudio-audio-plugins
```